# How to identify 3d objects using android phone

Tags: android

i am developing an android app. i want my app to recognize a 3d object to which the camera of my phone is exposed. currently i am able to achieve 2d object identification. however i would like to know how can 3d object identification be made possible in android. for eg if a user of my app focuses the camera lens on a microwave, the app should recognize this microwave is of Panasonic.
I went throught Google Googles, however  it is just able to identify 2d objects and my app can do that anyway. i would like to know a way to identify 3d objects.

Comment: If Google goggles doesn't do it, do you think this is an easy task that someone has a solution to?

Comment: Enroll for a PhD in Machine Learning, specialise in 3D machine vision, and come back with the answer in 3 years or more. We'll be waiting...

Comment: guys if you cannot answer just dont bother to comment. there is no reason for giving it a negative rating. and JBX thank you for giving me "Career" Advice. I don't need it.

Comment: And for your kind information Mr. JAvaNut, check Aurasma Kernel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no publicly available library or API for object recognition that handles 3D image files.

Considering that there is no standard file format for 3D images at this time, this is to be expected. Most 3D image files are propriety, usually combining two 2D images in a standard format like JPEG in their own container. A better solution if you want the user experience in 3D is to show the user the 3D image and send the server the 2D counterpart (involving converting the 3D format on the device to 2D onboard or taking a second picture in close succession in 2D).

Bottom line is that this will not work with Google Goggles or OpenCV. Even those are nowhere near being real-time. Remember, we are using slow computers with slow internet connections and low-end cameras.

As an Evo3D owner myself, I can understand your want. The Technology is just ahead of the available software at this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That helps! I will update this if i come across something good..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this information helps. I found out answer for the problem stated above. Aurasma is tool developed for Android and IOS that has the capability to identify real life objects. so referring to the same example as stated above, your android app containing aurasma kernel will identify the microwave and depending on what info you have supplied it will showcase that info every time it comes across the target image/product.
Even if Google has not come out with object identification technique, Aurasma has provided us with that solution. I think enrolling in PhD and doing my specialization in 3D machine vision was a longer process.. Some people showed poor maturity while replying to this post.. No issues.. if Aurasma kernel serves your purpose i will b happy..
Cheers..